# Solr query - not get correctly text matched

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I have this data:

```
{
    "id": "maxtor",
    "compName_s": "Maxtor Corporation",
    "address_s": "920 Disc Drive Scotts Valley, CA 95066",
    "_version_": 1526862455621288000
  }
```

And when I write this:

> solr/core/select?q=compName_s%3A*Maxtor*&wt=xml&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=compName_s&hl.simple.pre=&hl.simple.post=<%2Fem>

Return this:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">1</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">compName_s:*Maxtor*</str>
<str name="hl">true</str>
<str name="hl.simple.post"></em></str>
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="hl.fl">compName_s</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
<str name="hl.simple.pre"><em></str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="1" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">maxtor</str>
<str name="compName_s">Maxtor Corporation</str>
<str name="address_s">920 Disc Drive Scotts Valley, CA 95066</str>
<long name="_version_">1526862455621287937</long>
</doc>
</result>
<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="maxtor">
<arr name="compName_s">
<str><em>Maxtor Corporation</em></str>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>
</response>
```

---

All it's ok, but, when I will try this:

> solr/core/select?q=compName_s%3AMaxtor&wt=xml&indent=true&hl=true&hl.fl=compName_s&hl.simple.pre=&hl.simple.post=<%2Fem>

(compName_s:*Maxtor* to compName_s:Maxtor)

Return this:

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">0</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">compName_s:Maxtor</str>
<str name="hl">true</str>
<str name="hl.simple.post"></em></str>
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="hl.fl">compName_s</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
<str name="hl.simple.pre"><em></str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"></result>
<lst name="highlighting"/>
</response>
```

---

I want to return this:

```
<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="maxtor">
<arr name="compName_s">
<str><em>Maxtor</em> Corporation</str>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>
```

(I want get only the "Maxtor")

Comment: Whats the exact problem? COuld you please elaborate more on it?

Comment: I want this <lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="maxtor">
<arr name="compName_s">
<str><em>Maxtor</em> Corporation</str>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>

Comment: but there are no result for the query then how could you get the above format...it would be different when you found the result or matching data and different for not matching data.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting the xml response as below

```
<lst name="highlighting">
<lst name="maxtor">
<arr name="compName_s">
<str><em>Maxtor</em> Corporation</str>
</arr>
</lst>
</lst>
```

even if your data does not match or in case of you dont get any result.

Then in this case you need to dig out the code of the solr for the same
where in you can modify the response of it for the highlighting.

Currently it returns the response

```
<lst name="highlighting"/>
```

as it does not find the data in the result set , so the other high-lighting tags are not coming into picture.

For the rest tag check-out the source code and check how they are returning the response and check if it is possible for you to modify the same as per your requirement.